# Recommend VM software for Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

I am curious on people recommend VM’s on Ubuntu I have seen VirtualBox mentioned when looking around online, but on Windows I was not a fan of it. I’ve also been told Gnome has aVM package or something with in it. Any recommendations would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox is a very good VM application, especially the proprietary Oracle version which supports additional features by the installation of the accompanying Guest Additions and VirtualBox Extension Pack. The advantage of VMware over VirtualBox is that VMware Workstation 11 supports up to 2GB video memory whereas VirtualBox supports up to a maximum of 256MB video memory. VMware Workstation 15 and later supports virtual graphics memory up to 3GB. This additional video memory will give better performance when playing games on a Windows guest OS. The advantage of VirtualBox over VMware is that it is free software.